# iPhone NFC and third-party apps

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation, wallet, nfc

I'm having problems reading RFID tags using third-party apps on my iPhone 12 mini running iOS 16. When I use the built-in Shortcuts app, I can read various RFID tags: access tags, passports, library books etc. Those tags are obviously compatible with the iPhone hardware, but I have yet to find any NFC app that can read these. I have tried at least five different apps, the latest being [NFC Tools](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nfc-tools/id1252962749). According to [this link](https://www.shopnfc.com/en/content/20-nfc-iphone), it should be possible to read the UID on iOS 13+.

Comment: Which third party apps are you using? This might be a non-starter as Apple has highly restricted access to many hardware features through the official API / SDK and if this was allowed via SDK/API there should be buckets of apps doing exactly what you seek, no?

Comment: The app I have installed now is NFC Tools (linked in my question). But now that I have researched the topic some more, I guess most (if not all) access tag systems are using encryption with a private key in the tag to prevent cloning tags. I will edit my question to only ask why third-party apps can't read the UID since that should be possible on iOS13+.